# qnorm function in R. Using standard deviation vs standard error

Tags: r, machine-learning, normal-distribution, standard-error

I have calculated a Z value as below:

```
sample mean = 47.488
population mean = 45.292 
simple size = 250
SD population = 18.761

z_score = (xbar−mu)/(sigma/sqrt(n))
z_score = (47.488 - 45.292)/(18.761/sqrt(250))
z_score = 1.850744
Prob = 3.20%
```

I wanted to check the result by using qnorm function

```
qnorm(0.032, 45.292, 18.761, lower.tail = F)
```

However, I didn't get the same result. Instead, I had to use the standard error (18.761/sqrt(250)) = 1.187 for the standard deviation in the function to get the 47.488 I originally used.

```
qnorm(0.032, 45.292, 1.187, lower.tail = F)
```

I don't understand why in this example I need to use the SE rather than SD like in previous problems I have solved?

I am obviously missing something but I can't figure what it is.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If X is a normally distributed random variable with mean mu and standard deviation sigma then X is standardized by:

Z = (X - mu) / sigma

But you have standardized the random variable XBar which also follows a normal distribution if X is normally distributed. If X is independent identical distributed then XBar is normally distributed with mean mu and standard deviation sigma / sqrt(n).

For this very reason you have to use the standard deviation of XBar to get the right result.

```r
sample_mean <- xbar <- 47.488
population_mean <- mu <- 45.292 
simple_size <- n <- 250
SD_population <- sigma <- 18.761

# Standardizing X:
# (X - population mean) / SD population

# Standardizing XBar: 
z_score <- (xbar-mu)/(sigma/sqrt(n))
z_score
#> [1] 1.850744

p <- pnorm(z_score, lower.tail = FALSE)

qnorm(p, mean = mu, sd = sigma / sqrt(n), lower.tail = FALSE)
#> [1] 47.488
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>